# vuejs getting the value of a datepicker after selected

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

in vue js i want to get the result of 2 date-picker and get the different days between them but problem is i want to do it before form is submitted i mean when the user select dates i want to count the days and give price according to it i use a persian date picker i add it below if it may help :

```
https://github.com/talkhabi/vue-persian-datetime-picker
```

and here is my html markup :

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <label>start reserve</label>
                    <date-picker :auto-submit="true" v-model="date" :max="available_end.toString()"
                                 :min="reserve_end.toString()"></date-picker>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <label>end reserve</label>
                    <date-picker :auto-submit="true" v-model="date2" :max="available_end.toString()"
                                 :min="reserve_end.toString()"></date-picker>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and here is the vuejs part :

```
data(){
return {
date: '',
date2:'',
}
},
 components: {
        datePicker: VuePersianDatetimePicker
    },
```

the code contains much more so i cut it for better reading  and
i tried to use the date and date2 but they dont seem to work .

Comment: I guess, you can achieve it using computed properties. Please add the code what you tried to do so far.

Comment: i really have no idea how to get the i just tried this this.dateDiff = this.value      this.$emit('input', this.dateDiff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add a `@change="onChange()"` event to your date picker. Also because you have a `v-model` on each date picker the values of `this.date` and `this.date2` should be up to date at all times. Then in the `onChange` function you should be able to access `this.date` and `this.date2` and perform your date difference calculation in there.

If you add the same `@change="onChange()"` to both date pickers then the calculation of date differences will be performed when either of them change.

p.s make sure you are accessing your data with `this.propertyname`